# How old is Hela in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In **Thor: Ragnarok**, when Thor meets Surtur, he claims that:

> *I thought my father [Odin] killed you [Surtur] half a million years ago.*

Judging by this, it can be assumed that Odin himself is over 500,000 years old (at the very least).

In **Avengers: Infinity War**, Thor says that:

> *He is 1,500 years old.*

According to MCUWikia,

> *Hela was imprisoned for millenia by her own father.*

So, in the MCU, how old is Hela?

Comment: She's Hela old.

Comment: I wouldn't treat that half a million number as fact. It seemed like Thor was exaggerating - possibly to an extreme degree - when he said that.

Comment: It's unknown how old, but most bets would put Odin at a few centuries over 5000 (given the odin sleep probably helped him along and Hela probably several hundred to a couple thousand years younger.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Thor Ragnarok's hela (like many others) is not exactly the same character she is from the comics or other stories
The movies (MCU) has its own canon

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that may be true.. As you said, it could have been a figure of speech too.

Comment: @Edlothiad So, in short, it is unknown.. :( I thought that if what Thor said about Odin (being close to half a million years old), that would make Hela too a couple of hundreds of thousands of years old. That ***could*** answer why Hela  was so strong (because Asgardian powers grow exponentially with their age). Well, i'm disappointed :(

Comment: @mr.eaver I very well know that. As you can see, my question is only concerning the MCU Hela and nowhere have I asked about the comic book version

Comment: We don't know. Assuming Thor was exact in his statement saying he thought Surtur was killed a half a million years ago only means he heard that he died so long ago, not that Thor was alive. I think there was this hot chick in like 60BC named Cleopatra, but that doesn't mean I was there to see her with my own eyes. Realistically, I don't think we have any clue how old any of them are. All we know is when Loki said Asgard are mortal "Give or take 5,000 years..." Odin would easily be older thanks to the Odin Sleep, but beyond that we don't know.

Comment: Is there any dating information from *The Dark World* that can put an upper limit on it? Presumably she wasn't yet born while Bor was king.

Comment: Given the semi-archaic manner of speech of the Asgardians, is it possible Thor is using "million" here in its older sense (to mean a thousand), in which case, half a million years would be 500 years.

Answer (score 7):

First off, given the context of the scene I'm pretty sure Thor was just being facetious with the "half a million years" comment.

Secondly I don't think anything has been specified with regards to Hela's age, however in 'Thor: The Dark World' Loki infers that Asgardians live for about 5000 years.
Obviously she's older than Thor and as such can't be any younger than 1500, so with a little guesswork we can narrow it down a little more.

From the first 'Thor' movie we know that Thor just recently came of age and was expected to take the throne in Odin's stead. If we assume for a second that this is typical of Asgardian Princes, then we may further presume that this was roughly Odin's age when he succeeded Bor, married and produced an heir.

So with all that in mind we can safely say that Hela is between about 3500 and 2500.

Furthermore, given that Odin was still warring with the Ice Giants when Thor and Loki were infants, one could presume that Odin's new peace initiative and Hela's failed rebellion were fairly recent, which would have made her about 500 to 2000 years old at the time.
Split the difference and make her 3000 and that also makes her 1500 when she made a play for the throne, which seems to perfectly line up with the "coming of age" idea mentioned above.

Indeed if she was of an age where she expected to take over the throne and Odin refused her, (much like Loki) it could further inform why she took such drastic action against her own father.

Comment: If she were around when Thor and Loki were infants, then they would remember her.

Comment: @OrangeDog By "infants" I mean literally babies, so no they wouldn't. Also, I didn't say she was still around just that the conflict and treaty implies the aforementioned events could have been relatively recent. "Relatively recent" could be decades or centuries. That said, Hela specifically mentions Odin deciding to have Thor as a sign of his going soft, so she's at least aware of him, even if Thor was too young to remember her.

Comment: @Kris - I am not sure if it is possible, but the main reason I never answered similar to yours is that I wanted to address the time she was imprisoned and if that affected her "age" in some way. Given Valkyrie's time on Sakaar we don't know her true age and Heimdall never revealed if he "knew" Hela... from what I remember. I always assumed Hela was imprisoned for generations given that no one had even heard of her and all evidence of "Odin's conquest days" was covered up. Unless Odin swore all alive then to silence regarding her I would expect her to have been beyond a single generation...

Comment: @Odin1806 Valkyrie said that Hela killed everyone in the palace, and that Odin was always big on secrecy. So there's a good chance nobody servicing in the Palace during Thor's upbringing (save Odin & Frigga) was present for those events. Indeed it's entirely possible nobody outside the palace at the time knew what happened either.

Comment: @Kris - True, but Palace != City. And everyone had to know Hela. She was only banished when she became too grandiose. Up to that point she was Odin's daughter and beloved. If everyone lives 5k years and Hela still aged normally in her exile, we are still in the same generation and someone would have to still be alive who remembered her from before. If that was the case, then Hela's return would not be such a surprise. Also, in the first film when addressing the masses Odin says "Thor, my first born..." So either everyone who knew different was dead or Odin demanded her existence suppressed...

Comment: @Odin1806 It's a *really* big palace. Huge. I can easily see a small war taking place in those halls and nobody outside being any the wiser. Odin could have spun any story he liked, or just kept silent. It is a monarchy after all, not a democracy. The King is accountable to anyone but himself. Even if some old timers outside the palace remembered Hela: so what? The heir to the throne probably didn't spend a lot of time palling around with the commoners.

Comment: Your not understanding my point... I am saying that she is more than just one generation old. Sure the palace is big but everyone on Asgard would know who Hela is, regardless of meeting her. Everyone knew Thor and Odin right?! Even if they didn't meet. All the non combatants would have known who she was and realized she was never around anymore. I am saying since no one knew her she must have been a few generations old and that her "prison sentence" affected her age. If it was the same generation someone would have mentioned her in 1500 years or so at least once to Thor and Co.

Comment: @Odin1806 As described above, it's established that Asgardians live about 5000 years. Odin is Asgardian and we see him apparantly dying of old age. ergo, Hela was born less that a generation ago.

Comment: This is turning into chat, but Odin was way older than just 5000 years old. He had been using the Odinsleep to extend his own lifespan... we of course do no know for sure his exact age, but we know the Odinsleep extended his life. If I remember correctly it is even mentioned that the Odinsleep stopped working for him... So again, if Hela was in some sort of stasis or time was effected in her exile (similar to how it was on Sakaar) she could actually be much older. If you still do not understand what I am trying to get across then we can jump into chat, but you are missing the point entirely...

Comment: @Odin1806 So far as I can determine, there's no mention anywhere in the movies of the Odinsleep extending his lifespan, only of it recharging the Odinforce which gives him his unique powers. It's not impossible that it also makes him live longer, but there's no explicit indication of this.